# How to create a basic slider in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a HTML Slider with css only not using javascript.

Here is my attempt, how can i improve it?
https://codepen.io/fearless23/pen/GELXma

I just want to create a basic slider only using CSS only. Dont want to any Javascript

HTML

```
<div class="slides-container">

  <div>
    <input id="slide1" type="radio" name="login-slide" class="hidden" checked>
    <div class="slide">Slide1</div>
    <label for="slide1" class="slide-dot"></label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="slide2" type="radio" name="login-slide" class="hidden">
    <div class="slide">Slide2 </div>
    <label for="slide2" class="slide-dot" style="left: 12.52em;"></label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="slide3" type="radio" name="login-slide" class="hidden">
    <div class="slide">Slide3 </div>
    <label for="slide3" class="slide-dot" style="left:14.52em;"></label>
  </div>
        
</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slides-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2em 2em 5em;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.slides-container input[type="radio"]:checked + .slide {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  hieght: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
label.slide-dot {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 10.52em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slides-container input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  background: #2ca58d;
}
```

Note: Formatted original question so that I can ask questions again on StackOverflow :(

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: Did you even try something by yourself? If not then I guess you're expecting someone here to work for you for free

Comment: just wait guys uploading pic

Comment: pic is online.. please reply

Comment: i am using twiiter bootstrap for whole of the site, stuck in this part.... i have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS only.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh Stack Overflow is not a site where you can request code. We can help you with coding problems or general questions about software engineering, but we won't write code for you if you haven't done any attempts yourself. Anyway, I don't quite understand your first point. Where do you want to place any text?

Comment: And those two points of yours, I think those should be separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should really read up on how to work with HTML and CSS. I recommend reading the explanations at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) about [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). What you want to know about is in this case primarily lists and links (html-wise) and the funny things you can do with borders (css-wise). For example, to make css circles, David Walsh has a [nice blog-entry](http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles).

I also have to agree with Mr Lister, that you're two points are indeed separate questions. In fact, they are different technologies: Where the first is an HTML/CSS question, the latter is a javascript question.

A friendly advice: Don't want everything from the start. This will depress (I know that!). Make yourself comfortable with how HTML works, especially crosslinking pages and content. Once you get the hang of that, experiment with javascript (imho jQuery is very accessible, as in: leads to results fast). Hint: You want to experiment with the `display: none` CSS-attribute and the `div#id.show()` functions of jQuery.

Good luck with that, and have fun (that's what it all should be about)!

Comment: thanks...just needed a quick way to do it.... rest of site i am developing with twitter bootstrap....just a landing page designis different